# Inputs bug in Laravel 4 project

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, controller

Iam new to laravel and php and i lack experience.Im working to an already build project and there is bug that i cant fix in the ***"SeminarController"*** here is the code :

```
                if(Input::has('relative_link_titles')){
                $rldesc = Input::get('relative_link_titles');
                $rllinks = Input::get('relative_link_urls');
                $array = array_combine($rldesc,$rllinks);

                while($ar = current($array)){
                    $val = Relative_PackageLinks::where('relpl_desc',key($array))->get();
                    if(empty($val[0])){
                        $newlink = new Relative_PackageLinks();
                        $newlink->relpl_desc = key($array);
                        $newlink->relpl_packageid = $id;
                        $newlink->relpl_link = current($array);
                        $newlink->save();
                    }
                    next($array);
                }

                $result = Relative_PackageLinks::whereNotIn('relpl_desc',$rldesc)->delete();
            } else {
                Relative_PackageLinks::where('relpl_packageid',$id)->delete();
            }`
```

when i press save if the input **'relative_link_titles'** have the same name it cleans all the table i dont understand why so anyone experienced with php and laravel will be a lot of help answering this.Thank u all !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  did it it was easy i just had to add     `where('relpl_packageid',$id)->`to $result and to $val so the while loop check for everytime to a specific $id

Answer (score 0):

The array returned from Input::get() will be an indexed array not an associative array. Therefore when you do `key($array)`, it is passing  0, 1, 2, etc. instead of the text of the input

Also, using `while` will confuse the situation; better to use `foreach`.

Try this, although it's hard to know exactly what you're trying to do without some explanation of what is saved in each field.

```
$rldesc = Input::get('relative_link_titles');
$rllinks = Input::get('relative_link_urls');
$array = array_merge($rldesc, $rllinks);

foreach($array as $value) {
   $val = Relative_PackageLinks::where('relpl_desc', $value)->first();

   if(!$val) {
      $newlink = new Relative_PackageLinks();
      $newlink->relpl_desc = $value;
      $newlink->relpl_packageid = $id;
      $newlink->relpl_link = $value;
      $newlink->save();
}

$result = Relative_PackageLinks::whereNotIn('relpl_desc',$rldesc)->delete();
```

Comment: i want it to save both inputs for the same seminar :S sorry if i confuse you im very new to laravel php and web development

Answer (score 0):

here is the **view** blade , also i want these inputs for each **seminar** im my project,the fact is that with the code above the save dont let the same **"description link"** to enter or deletes all the table *(relative links)*

```
<table id="relative-links-output" class="table table-striped table-hover">
            @foreach($relative_links as $rl)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $rl->relpl_desc }}</td>
                <td>{{ $rl->relpl_link }}</td>
                <td class='col-md-1'><a href='#' class='remove-relative-link btn btn-danger'><i class='fa fa-minus'></i></a></td>
                <input type="hidden" name="relative_link_titles[]" value="{{ $rl->relpl_desc }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="relative_link_urls[]" value="{{ $rl->relpl_link }}">
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </table>
```